# I.V.T Continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and has the property that, for any $k$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = k$, then $f$ must be continuous on $[a,b]$.

True or False?

I guess it is true based on the I.V.T. But I am unsure how to prove it. Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Darboux_property

Comment: It is false. Think of a constant function $f$, but changing one value of $f$ in the middle of $(a, b)$.

Comment: What do you mean by changing one value of f in the middle of $(a,b)$? Thanks

Comment: The result as stated is false as seen in the answers given below. However it is an instructive exercise to prove that it is true under the additional hypothesis that $f$ is monotone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false ! take $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&if\ x\in[-1,0]\\1-x&if x\in(0,1]\end{cases}$$

Comment: For $f(x) = 1-x$, the $0$ is not included right?

Comment: yes ! But there exists a $c\in(-1,1)$ s.t. $f(c)=0$.

Comment: When u put it like $]-1,1[$, what does it mean? the symbol $][$?

Comment: I re-edited my post. $]a,b[$ is $(a,b)$.

Comment: So in this case, $f$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$ because there exists a $c \in (-1,1)$ such that $f(c) = 0$? Am I right? So here $k = 0$?

Comment: no $f$ is not continuous on $(-1,1)$ because it's not continuous on $0$ but there exists a $c\in(-1,1)$ s.t. $f(c)=0$ (in fact, $c=0$).

Comment: for the first equation $f(x) = x$ shouldn't it be if $x \in [-1,0)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\dfrac{1}{x} & \text{if $x\ne0$} \\
0 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, but $f'(x)$ is not continuous; indeed
$$
f'(x)=2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}
$$
for $x\ne0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

However $f'$ satisfies the IVT because of a [famous theorem by Darboux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)).